# is there a way to shorten if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a better way to type the if statement

```
if( x > rah || y > rah|| x < 0 || y < 0)
```

as this looks untidy and perhaps requires more computation than is needed

Comment: You can encapsulate this in a `method` call to make it cleaner...just return a `boolean`    `true` or `false`

Comment: if you're worried about the speed hit from having to do 4 comparisons and some `or`s, you're undoubtedly optimizing the wrong things to begin with.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Mathematically I don't think you can make this any smaller.

Answer (score 1):

It may look untidy, you could do this:

```
if (!between(x, 0, rah) || !between(y, 0, rah))
```

however, if you're thinking about excessive computations, you should order your conditions in order of likelihood to take advantage of the short-circuit operator ||.  This is the only way to actually reduce computations.

Comment: Well, since it looks like a check if `x` and `y` are in bound of something I would reflect that in the method name: `!inBound(x, 0, rah)` or to avoid the negation, just use a proper method: `outOfBound(x, 0, rah)`. But I also would use a dedicated method like you did.